# Unknown Bug - Pin Head Size Round Black Hard Shell found in Vegi Garden

Tags: bug-identification

This bug appeared on the underside of a pepper plant and has spread through out my vegetables. It is about the size of a pin head. it is black with a hard shell. It leaves a trail behind it but i never see it moving. it does not look segmented but then it is so small and I don't have a magnifying glass. This is in the Orlando Florida area.

I have my thumb in the picture so you can see the size comparison.
[image]

Comment: Looks like a scale insect of some description, though this is not an identification by any means.

Comment: i tried to get it identified at a nursery and they could not identify it. I was told it may be droppings. So i need to go out side in the dead of night to see if there is a bug on the plants at night.  i will post more when i do.